# Marketing Cloud SDK for iOS seems not to work properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilepush-ios

We are trying to integrate SFMC to an existing iOS app and we are struggling with the registration process for Mobile Push.

We are following all the steps in the iOS SFMC Documentation on [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/) even downloading the Learning App and replace all values with our AppID, AccessToken, AppEndpoint and MID, using DelayRegistration and setting a *test* contactKey.

The main problem is that we can't see our contact update on our Mobile Push dashboard.
We are encountering some 403 responses on the logs, but we our integrator does not know what that is and we are not finding any reference to it in the docs.

I attach the logs of the Learning App with our app values.

```
    2021-12-04 09:43:34.843888+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [umbrella] MarketingCloudSDK isReady = 1
MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m
line: 306
2021-12-04 09:43:34.844067+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] MarketingCloudSDKURLHandlingDelegate set
MarketingCloudSDK+URLHandling.m
line: 23
2021-12-04 09:43:34.844132+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] MarketingCloudSDKEventDelegate set to <LearningApp.AppDelegate: 0x281574de0>
MarketingCloudSDK+Events.m
line: 22
2021-12-04 09:43:34.844168+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] startWatchingLocation
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 1005
2021-12-04 09:43:34.844128+0100 LearningApp[470:26155] [controlchannel] network request SFMCNetworkRequest
MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m
line: 229
2021-12-04 09:43:34.903774+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] = 3
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 1052
2021-12-04 09:43:34.928903+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] didChangeAuthorizationStatus: <CLLocationManager: 0x28337a0b0>, CLAuthorizationStatus is 3
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 926
2021-12-04 09:43:34.928973+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] location has been enabled in the SDK with value: 1
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 1065
2021-12-04 09:43:34.929022+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] beacon has been enabled in the SDK with value: 1
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 1086
2021-12-04 09:43:34.929116+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] Location usage authorized and updating location information
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 936
2021-12-04 09:43:34.930192+0100 LearningApp[470:26157] [foundation] push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 1
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 1044
2021-12-04 09:43:35.145385+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] device token has been set in the SDK with value: 172704810ddd26d798ba56f582b34cb7cad06af9b3d26c57c7790d03e596a5cb
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 1122
2021-12-04 09:43:35.146894+0100 LearningApp[470:26159] [intelligence] [{"value":10,"analyticTypes":[4],"etAppId":"6ec6de3a-30d5-4e8c-98b9-c909a4381914","deviceid":"E3238E34-F71F-4A85-A05F-6DD35248520A","eventDate":"2021-12-04T08:41:44.621Z"},{"value":13,"analyticTypes":[4],"etAppId":"6ec6de3a-30d5-4e8c-98b9-c909a4381914","deviceid":"E3238E34-F71F-4A85-A05F-6DD35248520A","eventDate":"2021-12-03T17:40:43.574Z"},{"value":121,"analyticTypes":[4],"etAppId":"6ec6de3a-30d5-4e8c-98b9-c909a4381914","deviceid":"E3238E34-F71F-4A85-A05F-6DD35248520A","eventDate":"2021-12-03T17:20:36.334Z"}]
MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m
line: 681
2021-12-04 09:43:35.490464+0100 LearningApp[470:26157] [controlchannel] control channel response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x283159d80> { URL: https://mcvnbt6lw8r41dcm37h6gm0dtj-m.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/6ec6de3a-30d5-4e8c-98b9-c909a4381914/sync/E3238E34-F71F-4A85-A05F-6DD35248520A } { Status Code: 202, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        227
    );
    "Content-Security-Policy" =     (
        "upgrade-insecure-requests"
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sat, 04 Dec 2021 08:43:35 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "Referrer-Policy" =     (
        "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        DENY
    );
    "x-mashery-message-id" =     (
        "3fa15ffc-a941-44f5-b0e8-faaa8ed19355"
    );
    "x-mashery-responder" =     (
        "50-12"
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }
message response data:{
    nodes =     (
                {
            items =             {
                blocked = 0;
            };
            name = blocked;
            version = 1;
        },
                {
            items =             {
                inbox = 0;
            };
            name = pushFeaturesInUse;
            version = 1;
        },
                {
            items =             {
                inApp =                 {
                    gateEventProcessingMs = 1000;
                    maxDisplay = 50;
                };
            };
            name = appConfig;
            version = 1;
        }
    );
}

MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m
line: 254
2021-12-04 09:43:35.491240+0100 LearningApp[470:26157] [controlchannel] network request succeeded with status: 202
MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m
line: 266
2021-12-04 09:43:35.491586+0100 LearningApp[470:26157] [controlchannel] status code 202, processing only blocked node from sync route response
MarketingCloudSDKControlChannel.m
line: 289
2021-12-04 09:43:35.492351+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [migration] blocking MarketingCloudSDKMigration via control channel payload
{
    nodes =     (
                {
            items =             {
                blocked = 0;
            };
            name = blocked;
            version = 1;
        }
    );
}
MarketingCloudSDKMigration.m
line: 547
2021-12-04 09:43:35.531862+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [foundation] registration response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x283159d80> { URL: https://mcvnbt6lw8r41dcm37h6gm0dtj-m.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/registration } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        83
    );
    "Content-Security-Policy" =     (
        "upgrade-insecure-requests"
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sat, 04 Dec 2021 08:43:35 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "Referrer-Policy" =     (
        "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        DENY
    );
    "x-mashery-message-id" =     (
        "4b6aea35-a2f1-4e52-b549-6bb6fb7d70c1"
    );
    "x-mashery-responder" =     (
        "50-10"
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 764
2021-12-04 09:43:35.534814+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [inboxmessage] network request complete with status 403 taskError (null)
MarketingCloudSDKInboxMessage.m
line: 443
2021-12-04 09:43:35.535279+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [inboxmessage] message response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2831516e0> { URL: https://mcvnbt6lw8r41dcm37h6gm0dtj-m.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/6ec6de3a-30d5-4e8c-98b9-c909a4381914/message/?deviceid=E3238E34-F71F-4A85-A05F-6DD35248520A&messagetype=8&contenttype=2 } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        83
    );
    "Content-Security-Policy" =     (
        "upgrade-insecure-requests"
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sat, 04 Dec 2021 08:43:35 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "Referrer-Policy" =     (
        "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    );
    Vary =     (
        Origin
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        DENY
    );
    "x-mashery-message-id" =     (
        "35b9ada4-9344-471f-b443-1e0c61b3991f"
    );
    "x-mashery-responder" =     (
        "50-08"
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }
message response data:{"message":"Your account is inactive. MobilePush functionality has been disabled."}

MarketingCloudSDKInboxMessage.m
line: 452
2021-12-04 09:43:35.535716+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [inboxmessage] network request failed with status: 403
MarketingCloudSDKInboxMessage.m
line: 676
2021-12-04 09:43:35.538850+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [intelligence] {"message":"Your account is inactive. MobilePush functionality has been disabled."}
MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m
line: 702
2021-12-04 09:43:35.539586+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [intelligence] <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2831516c0> { URL: https://mcvnbt6lw8r41dcm37h6gm0dtj-m.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/event/analytic } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        83
    );
    "Content-Security-Policy" =     (
        "upgrade-insecure-requests"
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sat, 04 Dec 2021 08:43:35 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "Referrer-Policy" =     (
        "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Origin, X-HTTP-Method-Override"
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        DENY
    );
    "x-mashery-message-id" =     (
        "9e1592f3-0ad4-4954-ae13-3ab44e485e14"
    );
    "x-mashery-responder" =     (
        "50-12"
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }
MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m
line: 703
2021-12-04 09:43:35.541348+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [intelligence] Failure: http response code: 403
MarketingCloudSDKIntelligence.m
line: 730
2021-12-04 09:43:35.886229+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [event] No triggers for key $appOpen in event <AppOpenEvent: 0x2833642b0>
MarketingCloudSDKEvent.m
line: 801
2021-12-04 09:43:36.193499+0100 LearningApp[470:26159] [foundation] push has been enabled in the SDK with value: 1
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 1044
2021-12-04 09:43:43.352308+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] sfmc_setContactKey alexg@dribba.com succeeded
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m
line: 40
2021-12-04 09:43:43.352963+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] registration key path observer for blob
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 631
2021-12-04 09:43:43.353962+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] registration key path observer for blob
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 631
2021-12-04 09:43:43.354481+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] sfmc_setAttributeNamed key: LastName, value: Smith succeeded, attributes now {
    LastName = Smith;
}
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m
line: 361
2021-12-04 09:43:43.355953+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] registration key path observer for blob
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation.m
line: 631
2021-12-04 09:43:43.356380+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [foundation] sfmc_addTag Camping succeeded, tags now (
    iPhone,
    IOS,
    ALL,
    Camping
)
MarketingCloudSDKFoundation+ClientData.m
line: 116
2021-12-04 09:43:44.912711+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] didUpdateLocations: <CLLocationManager: 0x28337a0b0>, (
    "<+41.39142336,+2.14630724> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 4/12/21, 09:43:42 Central European Standard Time"
)
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 590
2021-12-04 09:43:44.922069+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] Received location update from iOS -> 41.391423,2.146307 @ 65.000000, age = 2.921344s.
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 606
2021-12-04 09:43:44.922216+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] Accurate location fix found!
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 617
2021-12-04 09:43:44.922336+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] Got a location fix! Updating.
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 1076
2021-12-04 09:43:44.923373+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] preparing to load geo-fence messages from server
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 404
2021-12-04 09:43:44.927280+0100 LearningApp[470:26140] [location] preparing to load beacon messages from server
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 251
2021-12-04 09:43:45.474770+0100 LearningApp[470:26159] [location] get location regions response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x283152180> { URL: https://mcvnbt6lw8r41dcm37h6gm0dtj-m.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/location/6ec6de3a-30d5-4e8c-98b9-c909a4381914/fence/?latitude=41.39142&longitude=2.14631&deviceid=E3238E34-F71F-4A85-A05F-6DD35248520A } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        83
    );
    "Content-Security-Policy" =     (
        "upgrade-insecure-requests"
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sat, 04 Dec 2021 08:43:45 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "Referrer-Policy" =     (
        "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    );
    Vary =     (
        Origin
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        DENY
    );
    "x-mashery-message-id" =     (
        "e02d8fda-57a1-4a94-831e-d0bdc9260eb7"
    );
    "x-mashery-responder" =     (
        "50-13"
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }
get location regions response data:{"message":"Your account is inactive. MobilePush functionality has been disabled."}

MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 447
2021-12-04 09:43:45.475795+0100 LearningApp[470:26159] [location] network request failed with status: 403
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 554
2021-12-04 09:43:45.476342+0100 LearningApp[470:26159] [location] network request retry in 60.000000 seconds
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 562
2021-12-04 09:43:45.559160+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [location] get beacon regions response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x28313a5e0> { URL: https://mcvnbt6lw8r41dcm37h6gm0dtj-m.device.marketingcloudapis.com/device/v1/location/6ec6de3a-30d5-4e8c-98b9-c909a4381914/proximity/?latitude=41.39142&longitude=2.14631&deviceid=E3238E34-F71F-4A85-A05F-6DD35248520A } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        83
    );
    "Content-Security-Policy" =     (
        "upgrade-insecure-requests"
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Sat, 04 Dec 2021 08:43:45 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5"
    );
    "Referrer-Policy" =     (
        "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    );
    "Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
        "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    );
    Vary =     (
        Origin
    );
    "x-content-type-options" =     (
        nosniff
    );
    "x-frame-options" =     (
        DENY
    );
    "x-mashery-message-id" =     (
        "9fa7c162-6a4d-4ca6-afb3-24e86342dc8b"
    );
    "x-mashery-responder" =     (
        "50-01"
    );
    "x-xss-protection" =     (
        "1; mode=block"
    );
} }
get beacon regions response data:{"message":"Your account is inactive. MobilePush functionality has been disabled."}

MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 294
2021-12-04 09:43:45.560439+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [location] network request failed with status: 403
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 369
2021-12-04 09:43:45.561017+0100 LearningApp[470:26154] [location] network request retry in 60.000000 seconds
MarketingCloudSDKLocation.m
line: 377
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would question your integrator as the logs clearly state, `"Your account is inactive. MobilePush functionality has been disabled."`.  You should contact your Salesforce account manager as it seems your application is not enabled.